# What to do when a Nikon J1's settings and indicators work but the screen is otherwise black and won't take pictures?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting

I recently received a Nikon J1 from a family member who wasn't using it. It took pictures no problem but then I misplaced the battery about 4 months ago. I just ordered a replacement battery off of amazon and powered it back up, but now the screen is black (although I still see indicators of all of the settings). I can go back through and see what is on the memory card, but I can't see anything out of the lense. I tried resetting all of the settings but that didn't work either.

Any ideas about what could be happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a Nikon-branded battery or third party?

Comment: Does the screen turn white if the lens is not mounted? If so, that would say the problem is with the lens. I assume the lens cap is off :)

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the camera. Turn on. Set camera to Auto mode, Auto ISO, Auto white balance, ISO to 0 and AF on. If you don't see anything in the screen as you point to something to take a picture, or it's black after taking a picture, the sensor is probably dead and the camera needs to be serviced.